# Apache Flink - Counter value displayed but meter values not displayed

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using **Flink 1.8.0** and running it on **EMR - Yarn** and would like to measure the throughput.

1. Because our operators are chained, we have added meters and counters in our code - essentially an async operator that makes API calls with kinesis as both source and sync. In the Application Master i.e. Flink's web UI, we are able to get the value for the counters but not the meters.

```
public class AsyncClass extends RichAsyncFunction<String, String> {

    private transient Counter counter;

    private transient Meter meter;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);

        this.counter = getRuntimeContext()
                  .getMetricGroup()
                  .counter("myCounter");

        this.meter = getRuntimeContext()
                .getMetricGroup()
                .meter("myMeter", new DropwizardMeterWrapper(new com.codahale.metrics.Meter()));
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        super.close();
        ExecutorUtils.gracefulShutdown(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, executorService);
    }



    @Override
    public void asyncInvoke(String key, final ResultFuture<String> resultFuture) throws Exception {


        resultFuture.complete(key);
        this.meter.markEvent();
        this.counter.inc();

    }
}
```

2. To measure the complete throughput of the application, we obviously need the throughput of all the task managers together. Using meters, we are able to get the metrics for individual task managers. Is there any way to measure it at the operator level?

Comment: Have you checked the log files for any warnings? (Maybe retry with DEBUG logging enabled) Are you bundling flink-metrics-dropwizard in the user-jar or is it placed in /lib? Does it work if you use custom dummy meter implementation?

Comment: @Chesnay Schepler, thanks for the reply.  I checked with a simple RichMapFunciton implementation for a map operator and it did not work there too. We are packaging the dropwizard dependency in the user-jar itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the meter displays whole number values and the rate is measured in decimals. When my load was a constant 1 event per second, it was actually measured as 0.9xxx something and hence was showing only 0 events per second.